# tikz color changing path

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have tried to answer the question from [TikZ: changing colour of a path half way along](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/tikz-changing-colour-of-a-path-half-way-along) with decorations - unsuccessfully. Maybe it is not possible!?

Can someone tell me why scoped path color change is not implemented?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean "unsuccessfully". The accepted answer worked for me without any modification.  Perhaps you are using a older version of the libraries. I am using the latest version of TeXLive2011 (updated today).

Comment: Yes there is no problem with the answer, but I was hoping that there was a highlevel solution, that did not involve doing the calculations yourself. I did mange to change the color, but at the same time the path was broke in two with no nice joining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scoped path colour is not implemented simply because it cannot be assumed to be implemented in the final document.  The lines and so forth in TikZ/PGF are written into the document using the document's method of drawing lines.  Since PDF, PostScript, SVG, and so forth have native ways of drawing lines, TikZ/PGF uses those.  Since TikZ/PGF tries to be backend-agnostic, it can only truly support those features that are common to all backends.  My guess is that for PDF and SVG, it isn't possible to change the colour of a path halfway (pretty sure about SVG, not so sure about PDF, don't know about PostScript).  So since the backends can't cope with it, neither can TikZ/PGF.