# Create a plot line with a gradient

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

TikZ allows you to have shapes with gradients like this

```
\fill [
    left color=red,
    right color=blue,
] (0,0) circle
```

is the same possible for a plot line?

Something like

```
\addplot[very thick, smooth, left color=red, right color=blue]
```

does not work.

Comment: Could you supply us with some example code that replicates your current problem? We call this a MWE. It should start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}.

(1) http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: I think not: [tikz-color-changing-path](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32294/tikz-color-changing-path), but you can try with an alternative solution proposed in [How to make a portion of curve red using TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162969/1952)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `mesh` plot style and a `colormap` for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:360, enlargelimits=false]
    \addplot [
        mesh, % Use line segments instead of one unbroken line
        colormap={}{ % Define the colormap
            color(0cm)=(red);
            color(1cm)=(blue);
        },
        ultra thick,
        point meta=x % Define the value that's used to determine the color
    ] {sin(x)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```