# drawing different parts of a line in different colours

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw different parts of a line in different colours. In the following code can each part of the line be drawn in different colour

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, green] (2.3,1.4) +(-27:2.2cm)-- +(153:2.2cm) +(42:1.88cm) -- +(-138:1.88cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please specify how you would like the output to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `edge` could perhaps be an option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, green] (2.3,1.4) +(-27:2.2cm) edge +(153:2.2cm) +(42:1.88cm) edge[blue] +(-138:1.88cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32294/ and the linked questions, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270001/ for a different situation and approach.