# How to \draw a path between several nodes with some segments dotted?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to do something like

```
\draw (node1) -- (node2) {[dotted] -- (node3)} -- (node4) {[dotted] -- (node5)} -- (node6);
```

There is no error message but the path comes out without any dotted parts, just everything same plain path.

Of course I could make several separate paths but in the "real" case there are about twenty segments that I would like to make alternatingly solid and dotted.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can't just change the line style underway. If you are using edges, you could, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437926/121799).

Comment: If the nodes are alternating you could write just a simple ```foreach loop``` in which are only two coordinates connected by a solid/dotted line.

Comment: You can't change colors with an inline scope either. I suspect the problem is that paths are constructed as a whole, then "stroked" (see page 1102).

Comment: @marmot I believe this is the answer to my question. Why could I not want to use `edge`s??